# Umbraco 8. How to create submenus for RTE Frormat styles?

Tags: css, tinymce, umbraco, rich-text-editor

I have a lot of styles in the css file. How I can group by name this styles like in the picture?
[image]

I have css file like this:

[image]

How to create 2 submenus "Sizes" and "Weights"?